# Use a value from a script as a default value inside a form field?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
> <script
> src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     var html_city = '';
> 
>     $.get("http://[somedomain].com", function (response) {
>         $("#html_city").html(response.city);
>     }, "jsonp"); </script>
> 
> <div id="html_city" name="n_city"></div>
> 
> <form id="myForm" action="" method="post">  City: <input
> type="text" name="city" value=[**????**] /><br />  <button
> id="sub">Save</button> </form>
```

I don't know how to get the value that

```
<div id="html_city" name="n_city"></div>
```

puts onto the page, and use the same as a default value for the City field inside the form.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want `response.city` to be the default value for the input with name `city`?

Comment: You want to get the html of #html_city and use it on input[name="city"] element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('[name="city"]').val(response.city);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the code :

```
 $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
     $("#html_city").html(response.city);
     $('#myForm input[name=city]').val(response.city);
 }, "jsonp"); </script>
```

This will set your input to the same value on response received.

Comment: I've tested all three of these responses above and below and they all work great, but I can only select one, so in fairness I'll check the first by Tsalikidis.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
  $("input[name='city']").val(response.city);
}, "jsonp");
```